# How to access application files in Android/data/com.xyz....?

Tags: android, android-studio, root

so I am coding an app and in order to debug I need to access the package folder on my Smartphone so that I can look for saved files. The directory folder Android/data/com.***applicationName*** is always empty when I try to open it. I already tried to access hidden files but still without results.

Does the smartphone need to be rooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it must be rooted to access system files.
If you are planning to access your app data, you can call `getFilesDir();`